# Android Wear: BleLEScan is draining my battery

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os, battery

I am developing an app which needs data from the wear.

One of the type of data is BLE.

I am using BleLeScan:

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .build();
                filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
            }

mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
```

BLELeScan is draining my wear's battery. I know this because i tested with BLE scan and without it. The difference is huge, without BLE scan battery consumption per hour is about 3%, whereas with BLE scan it is >16%.

How can I optimize battery consumtion for BLELeScan? I need to run the scan continuously.

Comment: Continuous BLEScans are a battery drain and there is no way around it. Also, 10% seems a bit high. How much time for 10% drain?

Comment: @lakshman.pasala: I have edited the question to include exact data of battery consumption with and without BLE scan.

Comment: In addition to @Emil's answer, you may want to check this [support page](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6303917?hl=en) on how to troubleshoot Android Wear if your battery is draining quickly. Also, as stated in this [thread](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/32), when using the BluetoothLEScanner in SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER mode, callbacks seem to come just as fast as with SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY, even with the app in the background. It might be after testing, battery drain with it scanning all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a scan filter to match only what you are looking for. Otherwise the cpu will be woken up when not needed.

Also note that power consumption depends highly on which Android device and Bluetooth chip you have.

If you are only looking for a particular paired device to connect to, consider connecting directly to it with autoConnect = true.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as pointed out in answers and comments, BLE scan consumes a lot of battery power. How much does it consumes? It will depend on the device.

I optimized battery consumption of the application by running the scan for 12sec/min and then stopping the scan for next 48sec. After 48sec I am restarting the scan.

Note, I am not making any supporting object null, I am just stopping the scan after 12sec.

This approach helped me save battery consumption by more than 50%.